# How to get the Azure network security group object from the Azure virtual machine object using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $azRgName -Name $azVmName
```

I can get the nic:

```
$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id
```

but its **NetworkSecurityGroup** property is **null**.

How to get the network security group object from the virtual machine object?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Network security group object from the virtual machine object make use of below script:

```c
# Replace these values with your actual resource group name and virtual machine name
$azRgName = "RGName"
$azVmName = "vmName"

$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $azRgName -Name $azVmName
$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id
$nsgName = $nic.NetworkSecurityGroup.Id.Split("/")[-1]
$nsg = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgName -ResourceGroupName $azRgName
```

***Output***:

```c
ResourceGroupName Name    Location ProvisioningState
----------------- ----    -------- -----------------
aks-rg-test       vm1-nsg eastus   Succeeded
```

[image]

Comment: many thx. As I wrote in my OP, my $nic's NetworkSecurityGroup property is null. Do not know what is the difference, on the portal GUI, I can see and administer the my network security group...